# If $A$ is a $5 \times 5$ matrix with $\det A = −1$, compute $\det(−2A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If $A$ is a $5 \times 5$ matrix with $\det A = −1$, compute $\det(−2A)$.

This what I think the answer is, I'd be glad if you could confirm:
if $\det A=-1$ that means that $A\sim (-I)$. Therefore, $-2A$ is equivalent to:

$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2  \\
\end{array}} \right)$$

Hence, 
$| - 2A| = {2^5}$

Comment: Yup, if you know that $\det (A.B) = \det(A) . \det (B)$, it should be much easier. A special case of it is $\det (\alpha . A) = \alpha^n . \det(A)$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and $n$ be the numbers of columns (or rows) of the matrix. Since $\alpha . A = \left( \begin{array}{lllll} \alpha & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 0 & \alpha & 0 & \dots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \alpha\\ \end{array} \right) . A$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The determinant is a multilinear form: it's linear on every column hence
$$\det(-2A)=(-2)^5\det A=-(-2)^5=32$$